# CSS and Javascript missing in one of two almost identical pages

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

Good afternoon StackOverflow, I have two almost identical pages:

[image: IDE View]

Once deployed one of the Pages (Login.xhtml) loads everything correctly:
[image: Login.xhtml]

But the other page (Index.xhtml) doesn't import some of the CSS and JS:
[image: Content.xhtml]

I am confused as to why this would happen.

The elements themselves have identical formatting, this is one of the files being called (Login.xhtml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" >

    <body>
        <ui:composition>
            Login Content
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the other (content.xhtml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" >

    <body>
        <ui:composition>
            content Content
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any clue as to why this is occurring? I just can't wrap my head around it, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Further information, both Index.xhtml and Login.xhtml (The composition files) are in the same folder.

The resource files Login.xhtml and content.xhtml are both in the same folder as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem.

The problem of the missing Javascript and CSS libraries was due to the lack of Primefaces elements in the content.xhtml.

I fixed this by adding a Growl:

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
```

That doesn't display, to the file common.xhtml. While I *was* properly importing Primefaces jQuery using the line:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

Some of the scripts required other libraries that automatically import with Primefaces elements.

This may not be the elegant solution, but it became a solution that solves my issue nonetheless.

Good day, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the links manually do your Login.xhtml? When this is working it may depens on the controller.

Edit: Sorry saw your post to late.

---

Did you try to check there in the same folder and they work well to include them manually in your Login.xhtml? 
Are the paths correctly means are login and index are in the same folder?

Comment: This was cleared up in the edit a bit ago, yes both Login.xhtml and Index.xhtml are in the exact same folder.